Apache not loading openssl php extension although it's enabled
I just upgraded php from v7.4 to v8.3 on my testing environment that uses Apache as the web server.
I uncommented line extension=openssl and i can check it works when i run phpinfo(); outside of apache web server.
But when I do phpinfo(); via Apache, I see openssl extension is not enabled, although the php.ini file is the same.
Why Apache does successfully load my openssl extension and how to fix it ?

When you check phpinfo() through Apache, take notice to what php.ini-file it says it's using. If it's not the same as you changed, then change that as well and restart your web server. You can have different PHP settings for CLI (command line) and mod_php (Apache). When you do phpinfo() outside of the web server, it won't use the settings for the web server.

Ok I just figured it out.
Inside my php.ini the extension config by default looks like this extension=openssl and inside the ext/ folder the name of the extension is this php_openssl.dll
If I give the complete file name as this extension=php_openssl.dll it now works.
I previously got the exact same issue with the sqlsrv extension.
I don't understand the behavior though.

It should work, as of PHP 7.2.0, the extension name may be used instead of the extension's file name.
